# Panel won't display text

Tags: java

I'm supposed to make a window that displays a message but my message won't display, I just get an empty window.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MessageFrame extends JFrame{
    public MessageFrame(){
        setTitle("Message in a Bottle");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel message = new MessagePanel();
        add(message);
        setVisible(true);
        JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("Help me please im not having fun with this assignment.", JLabel.CENTER);
        messageLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
        messageLabel.setAlignmentY(0);
        add(messageLabel);  
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MessageFrame();
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to make it display?

Comment: `MessagePanel` is this standard warning dialog?

Comment: You should add the label before displaying the frame.

Comment: change to `JPanel message = new JPanel();` and maximize the window to see your text

Comment: Please post definition of class `MessagePanel`.

Comment: Are you just trying to display a `JLabel` in a `JFrame` ?

Comment: @MohamedSaligh The issue isn't the size. The issue is that he's adding a component to an already visible container. He would need to call `revalidate` on the parent container to allow the layout manager to re-lay the components, accounting for the newly added component. Or, he just needs to add the component before making the container visible to allow the layout manager to account for it initially, preventing the need to revalidate.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach would be the following:

Inside your main method, you call an instance of MessageFrame() where "frame" or any object name you choose, and set it to setVisible(true).

```
        MessageFrame frame = new MessageFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

- I added setLocationRelativeTo(null); by habit.

Now in you public MessageFrame() method, you set your title, size, close operation and message label like this:

```
public MessageFrame() {

    setTitle("Message in a Bottle");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("Help me please im not having fun with this assignment.", JLabel.CENTER);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentY(0);
    add(messageLabel);
}
```

In short, inside your main method, you call instances of your other methods.

the whole code should look something like this:

```
public class MessageFrame extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {



        MessageFrame frame = new MessageFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    }

}

public MessageFrame() {

    setTitle("Message in a Bottle");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel("Help me please im not having fun with this assignment.", JLabel.CENTER);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
    messageLabel.setAlignmentY(0);
    add(messageLabel);
}
```

}

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should clarify why it is wrong and how your approach helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are a beginner in `Swing`. So to show a message dialog, you could use out-of-box implementation:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Eggs are not supposed to be green.");
```

More details and configuration settings you can find at [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)